# How to delay a systemd unit until network is ready?

Tags: networking, systemd, cron

I've switched from cron to [systemd-cron](https://github.com/systemd-cron/systemd-cron) with my Debian unstable system, but now the daily "cron job" often fails, because it runs mixmaster which fetches its database from the Internet and if the cron-daily.timer gets triggered before the network is up, after wake-up from suspend to RAM, mixmaster can't reach the server.

```
Apr 24 11:02:23 run-parts[13608]: /usr/bin/mixmaster-update: Get failed for http://www.noreply.org/echolot/pgp-all.asc (500 Can't connect to www.noreply.org:80)
Apr 24 11:02:23 run-parts[13608]: Downloading of mlist and/or mixring failed (do you need a proxy?). Aborting.
Apr 24 11:02:23 su[13809]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mixmaster
Apr 24 11:02:23 run-parts[13608]: run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/mixmaster exited with return code 22
```

Is it possible to delay the timer until the network is up and running?

Comment: So the situation is you open your laptop lid, and then the timer triggered service immediately runs "quickly before the network has come up yet"?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes, it runs before the network (WLAN) is ready. Sometimes the WLAN connect takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use systemd timers instead of cron.

Then in your systemd-unit, you can specify [`After=network-online.target and Wants=network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).

Comment: This doesn't help, because the target becomes active after boot, but remains untouched when the network goes down due to suspend to RAM e.g.

Comment: If all else fails, you can add a "sleep" statement to the script you run, to have it wait for a period before attempting to connect, like `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60`

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth using systemd's timers rather than cron.  You should then be able to specify in the unit what it depends on.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Handling_dependencies

Comment: The systemd-cron package in Debian are the systemd timers to replace sysv-cron. https://packages.debian.org/sid/systemd-cron

Answer (score 0):

In my [setup](https://konfekt.github.io/blog/2016/12/11/sane-cron-setup) the cron job is run every minute, but quits if there is no internet connection, by a connectivity test such as

```
nc -zw3 github.com 22 || exit 0
```

When there finally is an internet connection, then, once a day, the anacron jobs are run.